# How to create json object that start with the id of the row of the form?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I’m a beginner with javascript and I don’t know if what I’d like to do is possible.
I have a page with a form, like this

```
<form class="list" id="myForm">
<div class="row" id="company_1"> 
    <div class="form-field">
        <label>Title1</label>
        <input name="title1" id="title1" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label>Title2</label>
        <input name="title2" id="title2" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-required="true">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="company_2"> 

    <div class="form-field">
        <label>Title3</label>
        <input name="title3" id="title3" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label>Title4</label>
        <input name="title4" id="title4" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-required="true">
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row" id="company_3"> 

    <div class="form-field">
        <label>Title5</label>
    <input name="title5" id="title5" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label>Title6</label>
        <input name="title6" id="title6" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-required="true">
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-100 tablet-auto desktop-auto">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-footer"> 
            <span></span><a class="button button-fill" onclick="saveData()">Save</a>
        </div>
    </div><              
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I’d like to create a json object that has for first element the id of each row, like this

```
   {
"company_1": {
    "title1": ..his value,
    "title2": ..his value,
},
"company_2": {
    "title3": ..his value,
    "title4": ..his value,
},
"company_3": {
    "title5": ..his value,
    "title6": ..his value,
}
}
```

I read that there is a function in javascript serializeJSON() but it takes all names togheter.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it OK if I use jQuery in my answer?

Comment: yes if it can help me with the problem :)

Comment: Your HTML has several problems: the `div` open/close tags are not balanced, and the `label for` references are referring to the correct `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `for .. of` loop to iterate the result of a `querySelectorAll` call:

```js
function saveData() {
    const result = {};
    for (const input of document.querySelectorAll(".row input")) {
        const cat = input.closest(".row").id;
        (result[cat] = result[cat] || {})[input.id] = input.value;
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<form class="list" id="myForm">
    <div class="row" id="company_1"> 
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="title1">Title1</label>
            <input name="title1" id="title1" type="text" value="this" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="title2">Title2</label>
            <input name="title2" id="title2" type="text" value="is" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="company_2"> 
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="title3">Title3</label>
            <input name="title3" id="title3" type="text" value="a" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="title4">Title4</label>
            <input name="title4" id="title4" type="text" value="demo" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="company_3"> 
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="title5">Title5</label>
            <input name="title5" id="title5" type="text" value="with" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="title6">Title6</label>
            <input name="title6" id="title6" type="text" value="inputs" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-100 tablet-auto desktop-auto">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-footer"> 
                    <span></span><a class="button button-fill" onclick="saveData()">Save</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

(run the snippet in fullscreen, so you can see the input form *and* the object literal that is generated for it.)

Comment: Hi Trincot, thank you for your help.. but I can't modify your snippet. I try to explain me.. in this case I have only two node before the input for this we have twice parentNode : input.parentNode.parentNode  right? but in other form I have more than two.. How can I retrieve the id of the row without say how many parentNode? is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use the [`.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) DOM method. I updated the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will do as you ask.

That said, the structure you've chosen is not ideal.

```js
$(() => {
  var data = {};
  [0,1,2].forEach(n => {
    let companyId = 'company_' + (n+1);
    let titleAId = 'title' + (n*2+1);
    let titleBId = 'title' + (n*2+2);
    let company = { };
    company[titleAId] = $('#' + titleAId).val();
    company[titleBId] = $('#' + titleBId).val();
    data[companyId] = company;
  });

  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<form class="list" id="myForm">
<div class="row" id="company_1"> 
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="title">Title1</label>
        <input name="title1" id="title1" type="text" value="1" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="title">Title2</label>
        <input name="title2" id="title2" type="text" value="2" size="40" aria-required="true">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="company_2"> 

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="title">Title3</label>
        <input name="title3" id="title3" type="text" value="3" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="title">Title4</label>
        <input name="title4" id="title4" type="text" value="4" size="40" aria-required="true">
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row" id="company_3"> 

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="title">Title5</label>
    <input name="title5" id="title5" type="text" value="5" size="40" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="title">Title6</label>
        <input name="title6" id="title6" type="text" value="6" size="40" aria-required="true">
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-100 tablet-auto desktop-auto">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-footer"> 
            <span></span><a class="button button-fill" onclick="saveData()">Save</a>
        </div>
    </div>              
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. var divArr = document.getElementsByTagName('div') will give you an array of all he divs that are in a page. You could then loop through the results with divArr.forEach((d,idx)), and use idx + 1 concatenated with the prefix 'company_'
2. If you are using jQuery, it would be $('div').each() to iterate through them.
3. If you are reading from database, such as oracle, you could us rownum as your line number and concatenate that with 'company_' and get the number in your result set
4. If reading from SQL Server, you could SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY fieldName ASC) AS Row. Also, the latest version SQL server has FOR JSON PATH, which can be used to generate the JSON for you.

Again, not sure where your source is based on your question, but one of these may be applicable.